# How do I link to an article on another web in TWiki?

Tags: hyperlink, web, twiki

I've got an article in Main.

I want to link to it from another Web, call it Acme.

I've tried

Main.MyLink

%Main%MyLink

but can't get it to work.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general syntax for that is

```
web.topic
```

so you should be fine with

```
Main.MyLink
```

if you want to link to a topic *MyLink* in a web named *Main*. If your web *Acme* (or your whole wiki) has disabled auto-linking in the preference settings, you need to use the square brackets notation, e.g.

```
[[Main.MyLink]]
```

or

```
[[Main.MyLink][my link]]
```

Comment: Main.MyLink works fine now. I don't know what was wrong before.